# How to create *_swap tables (w/ indexes) in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a `students` table in postgres that is populated via an external source. Each night we populate the `students_swap` table, and then after the long running operation is complete we rename it to `students` and the original table then becomes `students_swap` to be used the next day.

The problem with this is that when we add a new column or index to the original table we must remember to also do so on the swap table. I am attempting to automate some of this w/ the following:

```
-- Drop the swap table if it's already there...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students_swap;

-- Recreate the swap table using the original as a template...
CREATE TABLE students_swap AS SELECT * FROM students WHERE 1=2;

... populate the swap table ....

ALTER TABLE students RENAME TO students_temp;
ALTER TABLE students_swap RENAME TO ps_students;
ALTER TABLE students_temp RENAME TO students_swap;
```

This works well for creating the table structure but no indices are created for the swap table.

My question is how do I copy all of the indexes in addition to the table structure to make sure my original table and swap table stay in sync?

Comment: Alternativ scenario: 1) dump the schema using pg_dump 2) rename the schema 3) recreate and import the schema from the dump.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `create table ... like` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE students_swap (LIKE students INCLUDING ALL);
```

This will include indexes, primary keys and check constraints but will **not** re-create the foreign keys.

**Edit**:

`INCLUDING ALL` will also copy the default settings for columns populated by sequences (e.g. a column defined as `serial`). It sounds as if you want that. If you do not want that, then use `INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS` instead.

Comment: Also, sequences will be shared, but will belong to the original table only (if there are any).

Comment: Awesome! I never knew that existed! I guess I should create the `CREATE TABLE` documentation better next time :p